# How can I output a variable and formula answer in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to output the value of a variable and the output of a formula (if statement) on the same Excel cell. This is my code:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ServiceArea + "=IF('Discovery Form'!R[5]C[-9] = ""Yes"", "" International User"", "" Local Line No Voicemail"")"
```

The output shows up as the value of the variable `ServiceArea` and the entire formula `(=IF('Discovery Form'!R[5]C[-9] = ""Yes"", "" International User"", "" Local Line No Voicemail"")`. I would like the output to be the value of the `ServiceArea` variable and the output of the formula.

Example:

```
ServiceArea = TEST
```

Output:

> TEST International User

Comment: instead of `ServiceArea +Formula` do `Formula+ServiceArea`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be careful about the double-quotes and ampersands.  A very simple example:

```
Sub FormulaPlacer()
    Dim ServiceArea As String, DQ As String
    ServiceArea = " the sum is: "
    DQ = Chr(34)

    Range("B9").Formula = "=" & DQ & ServiceArea & DQ & " & (A1+A2)"
    MsgBox Range("B9").Formula
End Sub
```

[image]